# List and Classes in C#. Trying to get count of two list of different classes type

Tags: c#, class

I am having two lists, `ListA` and `ListB`. The type of `ListA` is `classA` and the type of `ListB` is `classB`.
I have one variable which chooses one of both classes.
From both, I need to get the count because I am building a generic page for different products. The page shows thevalues but, in the case of the list ,I need to get the count.

My idea is something like:

```
object l;

if (ProductType == "A") 
{
    l = new List<classA>();
    ...
}
else
{
    l = new List<classB>();
    ...
}

var counter = l.Count(); // it is not working
```

I am using an object to initialize the list but maybe I should use a generic `IEnumerable` object to do it (I don't  know).

`classA` and `classB` I assume they inherit from the same base.

The rest of the page is quite similar.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: It sounds like you need a `List<BaseProduct>()` that holds both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type of `l` to `System.Collections.IList`

E.g.

```
IList l;

if (ProductType == "A") 
{
    l = new List<classA>();
    ...
}
else
{
    l = new List<classB>();
    ...
}

var counter = l.Count; // Count is a property here.
```

Comment: I changed to IList but code is giving me IList interfice doesnt contains Count property

Comment: IList derives from the ICollection interface, which implements the Count property. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can type the variable as an `IList` or `ICollection` (non-generic) both of which `List<T>`  implements, and both of which can give you a `Count`.

Of course if you only care about the count and nothing else the other option is to simply type the variable as an `int` and have each section of the `if` statement assign the count directly, rather than the whole list.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to get the **Count**, then an `ICollection` will be enough.

I do not recommend using `IList` because you have access to the list itself, i.e. **adding** or **removing** elements.

```
ICollection collection;

if (ProductType == "A") 
{
    collection = new List<classA>();
    ...
}
else
{
    collection = new List<classB>();
    ...
}

var counter = collection.Count;
```

Comment: `.Count()` here is `Enumerable.Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T>)` - it doesn't work on non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. OP should use `IColletion`

Comment: `ICollection` Also does not have a `Count()` method.

Comment: Changed it to `Count` property. Thanks for reviewing